# Retrieve matched data from Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my collection data.

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aa0cc8a53e19d84f80842e1"),
        "states" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "1",
                "name" : "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
                "country_id" : "101"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "2",
                "name" : "Andhra Pradesh",
                "country_id" : "102"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "3",
                "name" : "Arunachal Pradesh",
                "country_id" : "101"
            } 
        ]
    }
```

I need `country_id` matched data

if country id  `101`, i need to get first data.

I tried:

```
db.states.find({states: {$elemMatch: {country_id:'101'}}})'

db.tb10_states.find({ "states.country_id": "101"} )

db.tb10_states.find({ "states": { "country_id": "101"} } )
```

This not works for me.

Suggest me How to get this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html) in projection, it will give you first matching element from nested array

```
db.states.find( { _id: ObjectId("5aa0cc8a53e19d84f80842e1") },
             { states: { $elemMatch: { country_id: "101" } } } )
```

To get more than one value you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

```
db.states.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        states: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$states",
               as: "state",
               cond: { $eq: [ "$$state.country_id", "101" ] }
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

Comment: its only get first data

Comment: I updated my question, i have two matched  data, this one how can I get that.

Comment: @Rajkumar.E, extended my answer

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned into above question please try executing following MongoDB query into MongoDB shell.

```
 db.states.find({
    states: {
        $elemMatch: {
            country_id: "101"
        }
    }
}, {
    'states.$': 1
})
```